# PHP iterate through sequental key values

Tags: php, arrays, oop

I am grabbing Pokemon data from a JSON API, that is showing values for any Pokemon. The aim here is to grab data that shows what games a Pokemon can be found in and which areas in the game they are found located.

https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/183/

This is accessed via its [encounters](https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/183/encounters) key value. I am particularly interested in accessing via :

['location_area']['name'] and ['version']['name']

As a good URL example: https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/183/encounters

Problem is, the encounters array index value is a URL, which I am accessing through my own Curl json function, which works fine, but will only give me array numeric index values.

```
public function getPokemonLocation($searchTerm)
{

    /*
    Get the Pokemon via search term name
     */

    $url = $this->baseUrl.$searchTerm;
    $pokemonLocation = $this->getUrl($url);

    /* 
        $pokemonLocationUrl is the encounters subset i the array URL 
    */

    $pokemonLocationUrl =  $pokemonLocation['location_area_encounters'];
    $pokemonLocationEncounters = $this->getUrl('https://pokeapi.co/' . $pokemonLocationUrl);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($pokemonLocationEncounters);
    echo "</pre>";


     /* 
        Now grab the data needed from the name of location and what game regions they are from 
     */

    $pokemonAreaEncounterArea = array();
    $pokemonAreaEncounterGame = array();

      foreach($pokemonLocationEncounters as $key => $encounter)
      {
         $pokemonAreaEncounterArea[] = $encounter['location_area']['name'];
          $pokemonAreaEncounterGame[] = $encounter['version_details'][0]['version']['name'];
      }
        $pokemonLocationAndRegion = array_combine($pokemonAreaEncounterGame,$pokemonAreaEncounterArea);

        // print_r($pokemonLocationAndRegion);

        return  $pokemonLocationAndRegion;
 }
```

Problem is, the encounters array index value is a URL, which I am accessing through my own Curl json function, which works fine, but will only give me array numeric index values.

I can easily get data, as shown above . Howwever would like to fully access all of the array indexes, not just one or a handful of data. Tempting to do this via multiple foreach, but would rather implement it cleanly.

EDIT: Here is 2nd example of Poke APi link above, if you get a 504 server Error - https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=73911ec678c850f9b1ff131ac7ee738c

Comment: pokeapi.co is giving 504 error. Can you supply a sample of the json data?

Comment: @Cemal, Sure I guess this link should suffice, https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=73911ec678c850f9b1ff131ac7ee738c

Comment: does this `$this->getUrl($url);` return (json_decoded)array or json?

Comment: What is your expected result, compared to what you are currently getting?

Comment: @Cemal - Yeah, it returns a json array via json_decode()

Comment: @dcrean Can you explain your expected result?  What you are resolution that you are actually seeking?  I can't understand what satisfies your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your json which is returning an index based array, this is how your code should be to work.

```
public function getPokemonLocation($searchTerm) {

    /*
    Get the Pokemon via search term name
     */

    $url = $this->baseUrl . $searchTerm;
    $pokemonLocation = $this->getUrl($url);

    /*
        $pokemonLocationUrl is the encounters subset i the array URL
    */

    $pokemonLocationUrl = $pokemonLocation['location_area_encounters'];
    $pokemonLocationEncounters = $this->getUrl('https://pokeapi.co/' . $pokemonLocationUrl);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($pokemonLocationEncounters);
    echo "</pre>";

    $pokemonAreaEncounterArea = array();
    $pokemonAreaEncounterGame = array();

    /*
       Now grab the data needed from the name of location and what game regions they are from
    */

    for($i=0,$size=count($pokemonLocation);$i<$size;$i++) {
        $pokemonAreaEncounterArea[] = $pokemonLocation[$i]['location_area']['name'];
        $pokemonAreaEncounterGame[] = $pokemonLocation[$i]['version_details'][0]['version']['name'];
    }

    $pokemonLocationAndRegion = array_combine($pokemonAreaEncounterGame, $pokemonAreaEncounterArea);

    // print_r($pokemonLocationAndRegion);

    return $pokemonLocationAndRegion;
}
```

to make it clearer

```
    for($i=0,$size=count($pokemonLocation);$i<$size;$i++) {
        $pokemonAreaEncounterArea[] = $pokemonLocation[$i]['location_area']['name'];
        $pokemonAreaEncounterGame[] = $pokemonLocation[$i]['version_details'][0]['version']['name'];
    }
```

this will allow you to traverse all elements in the result array, and put them on the same index in respective arrays of `$pokemonAreaEncounterArea` and `$pokemonAreaEncounterGame`

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the target data as you iterate like this:

```
$array=json_decode($json,true);
foreach($array as $item){
    $result[$item['version_details'][0]['version']['name']]=$item['location_area']['name'];
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'diamond' => 'great-marsh-area-6',
  'platinum' => 'sinnoh-route-215-area',
  'heartgold' => 'mt-mortar-1f',
  'ruby' => 'hoenn-route-120-area',
  'emerald' => 'hoenn-safari-zone-expansion-south',
  'leafgreen' => 'four-island-area',
  'black-2' => 'route-22-area',
  'x' => 'kalos-route-3-area',
)
```